# Rails 4.2 & Salesforce API with Restforce returning ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: rubygems, salesforce, omniauth, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to write a rails 4.2.0.beta2 app that will allow our organisation to interface directly with our salesforce instance.

I've been following this really useful entry [here](http://geekymartian.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-4-salesforce-oauth-implementation/).

I'm nearly there, i've got my app setup in salesforce, it appears to be firing off the request ok, I can get to the login page and enter my inforamation.

However I'm getting the following error upon callback.

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in SessionsController#create
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

enter code hereExtracted source (around line #21):

  def sanitize_for_mass_assignment(attributes)
    if attributes.respond_to?(:permitted?) && !attributes.permitted?
      raise ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
    else
      attributes
    end
```

I looked into my Sessions controller which is supposedly causing me a problem... but I can't work out what's going on.

Can anyone spot where i've gone wrong here?

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url
    end

    def destroy
      session[:user_id] = nil
      redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in relation to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452652/ruby-on-rails-error-making-new-app-rb55in-require/24453298#24453298) and [this bug](https://github.com/realdoug/omniauth-salesforce/pull/13).