# Restforce Gem, Salesforce API retuning OAuth2::Error Missing_OAuth_Token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I've been attempting to get Ruby on Rails 4.1 to talk to our salesforce instance using the `gem omniauth` and `gem restforce` as per this instruction link [here](http://geekymartian.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-4-salesforce-oauth-implementation/).

All seems to be going alright, I got things up and running, with a hyperlink that takes me to a salesforce login and seems to return to the callback correctly. However when it does i get the error:

`OAuth2::Error`
`Missing_OAuth_Token`

This leaves me really confused and mystified, my oauth token should surely be supplied by the callback?

I have my client_id and client_secret stored in the app and they appear to load in correctly. Adding my salesforce login and password through omniauth should provide all it needs right? I don't see anywhere else in the omniauth gem docs or restforce gem to stick an oauth token... and even then i'm not sure where i'd get it from.

I'd read that there had recently been some authentication failures with the gem `omniauth` and there is a current issue request to put out a new version. If I specify my gem to pull directly from the [github](https://github.com/realdoug/omniauth-salesforce). I get a similar bit distinct error that I have posted about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26589817/rails-4-2-salesforce-api-with-restforce-returning-activemodelforbiddenattrib).

Could anyone give any advice on:

1. Where I should expect the missing `Auth_Token` to come from (I really can't work out if I'm supposed to be providing it in my app or if that's what comes back from salesforce

   2. How would be best to go about debugging this? (i'd thought about using `debugger` but as it pings to code outside of my rails app i'm unsure how much help this would be.
   3. What the correct way would be to go about setting this up properly!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, tutorial author here :) . Some people have fixed this setting the `:instance_url` (naX.salesforce.com) manually when instatiating the Restforce . Have you tried it?

Comment: @geekymartian ! You are a legend for your help in getting me this far. Unfortunately the problem persists. Looking your code, I've hit my 'login via salesforce' link, gone to the authentication page, logged in and had the callback appear to go successfully, It's at this point the error is raised. I figured that if i went into the `rails console` at this point i could try manipulating the `current_user` object, but i get `NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for main:Object`... really stumped

Comment: Looking more closely at the webrick logs, this is the course of things:

`(salesforce) Request phase initiated.`
`Started GET "/auth/salesforce/callback?display=page&code=***...%**%**&state=***..." for 78.151.151.129 at 2014-10-31 12:02:14 +0000`
`(salesforce) Callback phase initiated.`
`(salesforce) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, Missing_OAuth_Token`

Comment: I've updated the post to work with the latest version of Rails, you can download the example https://github.com/bfagundez/rails-salesforce-oauth-template .

Comment: Many thanks martin, I'm going to try and get my authentication working by loading things up as environmental variables for a while. I have a feeling my core problem here is confusion about where I store my details, I've seen that the databasedotcom-oauth2 gem offers the potential to use .yml files, environmental variables but I figured here all that was covered by loading things into the initializer... anyway, thanks for the update. I'll check there and report back! Many thanks again for responding here!

Comment: hey @geekymartian I don't know what your update has changed, but it now works fine! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually a bug in the omniauth-salesforce gem - https://github.com/realdoug/omniauth-salesforce/pull/13.

There was a minor change to the way the Salesforce API worked which was resolved in the above pull request. You must have upgraded your gem which solved the problem.